# Magento upgarde from version 1.9 to magento 2 using migration tool taking so much time

Tags: php, magento-1.9, data-migration, magento2

I have a magento website which have the version 1.9.0. I have try to upgrade using this migration tool [Migration tool](https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration/releases)
. I have added the database name of magento 1 and create a fresh database name in the other table and click next step and data processing taking several hours can you please tell why its happening I will attach the screenshot of it also. I am also trying in my local system only. What is the mistake I have done in this why it takes this much time can you please help me in this.

[image: Data migration]

Answer (score 0):

This is normal.

The data migration isn't a simple copy of your database. Magento 2 reads your whole database, and rewrites it to a new format. It is also doing a number of consistency checks to ensure your data comes through without error.

Depending on the number of products and assorted data you have, and the specs of the machine you're running it on, this can take several hours.

In the migration guide, the Magento team noted that their [test data migration](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-overview-practices.html) takes about 9 hours.

The best you can do to speed it up is run it on a more powerful machine. There's not much else to do; by its nature, it is a very time-consuming process.